# Dual Boot Ubuntu 14.04 on Win 10 PC - WiFi not Enabled

Tags: 14.04, networking, dual-boot, drivers

I am new to Linux, and auditing a CS class - it is recommended we use Ubuntu 14.04, so I did a dual boot install on my Win 10 PC, following instructions I found online.  Worked ok except now Ubuntu does not have any wireless access.  Network manager shows disconnected, no networks recognized, not even an "enable wifi" option in the task bar.  From reading online, it may be a missing driver issue, but I am running a newer laptop with no wired connection, and only wifi, so I cannot download a driver.  Wireless card is Intel AC 8265, and works fine when I boot in Windows mode.  I copied a driver to USB and am attempting to install it, but am apparently doing something wrong.  I am a Linux (and programming) novice.  Can anyone help?  Is it a driver problem, or something else?  And if driver problem, how do I install the correct driver?  Thanks much in advance for help with this very frustrating problem.

Comment: The Intel 8265 is a relatively new wireless device. On the other hand, Ubuntu 14.04 is relatively old, almost 5 years old, version. The driver in 14.04 doesn't cover your device. You could install 18.04 LTS or undertake arduous but do-able steps to install either a later kernel or a later driver version. What is your choice? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply.  I would probably prefer 18.04 install and take my chances with the course software working as intended with newer Ubuntu.  It was recommended we use 14.04 for compatibility reasons, but if that is not possible...  Very dumb follow-on question - how do I uninstall 14.04 and reinstall 18.04 on top?  Sorry to ask, like I mentioned earlier I am brand new to Linux.

Comment: I suggest that you try the live session of 18.04 and confirm that the wireless works, which I am confident it will.Then select Install Ubuntu and one of the options you will be offered is nuke and replace 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade you would have to do a `sudo apt full-upgrade`. But you would have to have an internet connection. Have you tried the wired network to see if that at least works ?

Comment: I have not tried a dvd iso. But that should work for upgrading as well.